# ARCore: execute each frame instead of when touching the screen (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working in a project which needs to execute a function every frame, but without clicking the screen. I dont know why putting the code in the Update function doesnt work (it needs all time and anyway, to touch the screen to execute the code). I put here the part of the code I want to play every frame:

```
     anchor.transform.position = Vector3.zero; 
     hotPoint.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
     _androidPosVector3ZeroText.text = anchor.transform.position.ToString(); 
     _camPosText.text = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position.ToString();
```

I am going to explain how it works: I have placed the android icon and also its anchor in the 0, 0, 0 world position. I do that because I always want to know where is the center of my world in the app. And finally, I want to know every frame which is the camera position relative to that center. I show each value in a text. And this code is in the Update function, and I dont know why I have to touch the screen to execute it, if it is NOT in any if or something...

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If it's directly in Update() I don't see a reason this wouldn't execute. please post more of the relevant code to show where these are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I got it. You just have to put the code you want to apply every frame, just over the "if" that makes to put the Android prefab when you touch the screen.
I dont know why, but that works. Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the full Update function. My part of the code is in the final lines, and it is directly invoked in Update.

```
    public void Update()

    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        _QuitOnConnectionErrors();

        // Check that motion tracking is tracking.
        if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
        {
            const int lostTrackingSleepTimeout = 15;
            Screen.sleepTimeout = lostTrackingSleepTimeout;
            if (!m_IsQuitting && Session.Status.IsValid())
            {
                SearchingForPlaneUI.SetActive(true);
            }

            return;
        }

        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;

        // Iterate over planes found in this frame and instantiate corresponding GameObjects to visualize them.
        Session.GetTrackables<TrackedPlane>(m_NewPlanes, TrackableQueryFilter.New);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_NewPlanes.Count; i++)
        {
            // Instantiate a plane visualization prefab and set it to track the new plane. The transform is set to
            // the origin with an identity rotation since the mesh for our prefab is updated in Unity World
            // coordinates.
            GameObject planeObject = Instantiate(TrackedPlanePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity,
                transform);
            planeObject.GetComponent<TrackedPlaneVisualizer>().Initialize(m_NewPlanes[i]);
        }

        // Disable the snackbar UI when no planes are valid.
        Session.GetTrackables<TrackedPlane>(m_AllPlanes);
        bool showSearchingUI = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_AllPlanes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (m_AllPlanes[i].TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                showSearchingUI = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SearchingForPlaneUI.SetActive(showSearchingUI);

        // If the player has not touched the screen, we are done with this update.
        Touch touch;
        if (Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase != TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Raycast against the location the player touched to search for planes.
        TrackableHit hit;
        TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
            TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;


        Frame.Raycast(0.5f, 0.5f, raycastFilter, out hit);
        float distance = hit.Distance;

        if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit) && Time.time < 15)
        {
            hotPoint = Instantiate(AndyAndroidPrefab, Vector3.zero, hit.Pose.rotation); 

            // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
            // world evolves.
            anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

            anchor.transform.position = hotPoint.transform.position; 
            _androidPosVector3ZeroText.text = anchor.transform.position.ToString(); 
            _camPosText.text = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position.ToString(); 

            // Andy should look at the camera but still be flush with the plane.
            if ((hit.Flags & TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon) != TrackableHitFlags.None)
            {
                // Get the camera position and match the y-component with the hit position.
                Vector3 cameraPositionSameY = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position;
                cameraPositionSameY.y = hit.Pose.position.y;

                // Have Andy look toward the camera respecting his "up" perspective, which may be from ceiling.
                hotPoint.transform.LookAt(cameraPositionSameY, hotPoint.transform.up);
            }

            // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
            //hotPoint.transform.parent = anchor.transform;

            hotPoints.Add(hotPoint); 

            hotPointDistanceToCamera = Vector3.Distance(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position, anchor.transform.position); 
            hotPointDistancesToCamera.Add(hotPointDistanceToCamera); 
            distanceTexts[0].text = "Hot Point " + (Time.time.ToString()) + ": " + hotPointDistancesToCamera[0].ToString();


            Text newText = Instantiate(distanceText, canvas.transform, false); 
            distanceTexts.Add(newText); 
            if (lastText != null)
            {
                newText.rectTransform.localPosition = lastText.rectTransform.localPosition + new Vector3(0, -30, 0); 
            }
            lastText = newText;
        }

        anchor.transform.position = Vector3.zero; 
        hotPoint.transform.position = Vector3.zero;

        _androidPosVector3ZeroText.text = anchor.transform.position.ToString(); 

        _camPosText.text = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position.ToString();
    }
```